# Maven not creating target/classes directory

Tags: java, maven

So when I try to compile my code I was at first confused why my depending code could not compile until I checked my local maven repos and found out that the dependency jar was not being created properly. So I traced the issue back all the way to IntelliJ maven.

When compiling Maven creates a target/classes folder that contains all classes used for compilation. however in my case (for whatever reason) maven creates a "classes" file in target, and the compiler fails saying `javac: not a directory: C:\Users\...\target\classes`
Why is maven not creating the folder correctly but instead chooses to create a file?

These are all my dependencies/plugins

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.test.Main</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                                    <exclude>jmock:*</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*:xml-apis</exclude>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.maven:lib:tests</exclude>
                                    <exclude>log4j:log4j:jar:</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

[image: Here is a picture, these Should be 3 folders, but instead one is a file]

Edit:
I tried creating the `target` folder myself, however that just lead to a different error.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) on project License: Error creating shaded jar: Could not replace original artifact with shaded artifact!
```

Comment: Also create the classes folder under the target folder manually! But don't ever mvn clean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it wasn't working, but it started working after I manually put in

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

in the pom file.
normally, that is the "default" setting but after that it worked.